# How to specify attachment encoding in mutt command line?

Tags: centos, command-line, email, mutt, character-encoding

I'm trying to send an email with attachment from a perl script.

First, I create the attachment (an xml file):

```
open(XMLFILE, ">:utf8", $xmlfile);
print XMLFILE "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
print XMLFILE "<data>\n";
#print XMLFILE "...\n";
print XMLFILE "</data>\n";
close (XMLFILE);
```

I also tried `open(XMLFILE, ">", $xmlfile);` with `binmode XMLFILE, ":utf8";`.

Then I send the email like this:

```
open(MUTT, "|/usr/bin/mutt -s \"TestSubject\" -a $xmlfile \"test\@example.com\"");
binmode MUTT, ":utf8";
print MUTT ("TestBody");
close (MUTT);
```

Nevertheless, both the text part and the attachment have `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`.

I also tried `open(MUTT, "|/usr/bin/mutt -e \"set file_charset=utf-8\" -a $xmlfile ...`, but this gave me an `Error in command line: file_charset: unknown variable`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to update the mutt version, but I found a workaround - others may find this helpful, too.

Including a comment with special characters lets perl and mutt choose the correct (utf-8) encoding (probably the 'ł' would suffice, but the intent gets clearer with the umlaut characters):

In the xml this is what it looks like:

```
<?xml ... ?>
<?comment <!-- ł€èÄöÜß --> ?>
<content>
    ...
</content>
```

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the excellent Arch wiki has the answer (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mutt). Quoting verbatim:

> E-mail character encoding
>
> When using Mutt there are two levels where the character sets that
>   must be specified:
>
> 1. The text editor used to write the e-mail must save it in the desired encoding.
> 2. Mutt will then check the e-mail and determine which encoding is the more appropriate according to the priority you specified in the
>      send_charset variable. Default: "us-ascii:iso-8859-1:utf-8".
>
> So if you write an e-mail with characters allowed in ISO-8859-1 (like
>   'résumé'), but without characters specific to Unicode, then Mutt will
>   set the encoding to ISO-8859-1.
>
> To avoid this behaviour, set the variable in your muttrc:
>
> `set send_charset="us-ascii:utf-8"`
>
> or even
>
> `set send_charset="utf-8"`
>
> The first compatible charset starting from the left will be used.
>   Since UTF-8 is a superset of US-ASCII it does not harm to leave it in
>   front of UTF-8, it may ensure old MUA will not get confused when
>   seeing the charset in the e-mail header.

You can do this from the command line rather than from muttrc by prepending

```
-e 'set send_charset="utf-8"'
```

to the command flags.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$ mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" Email address -s "subject" < test.html
```

Change it around for what ever content_type you want. In Perl something like this:

```
open(MUTT, "|/usr/bin/mutt -e \"set content_type=text/xml\" -s \"TestSubject\" -a $xmlfile \"test\@example.com\"");
```

If you don't want to use `mutt` you can use `mail` instead:

```
### method #1
$ mail -a 'MIME-Version: 1.0' -a 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1' -a 'X-AUTOR: Some Guy' -s 'MTA STATUS: mail queue' <to user>  -- -f <from user>  < /tmp/eximrep.xml

### method #2
 $ mail -a 'Content-type: text/xml; charset="us-ascii"' <to user> < /tmp/file.xml
```

You could also do this using sendmail directly:

```
(
echo "From: myuser@example.com"
echo "To: user@example.net"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;"
echo ' boundary="BOUNDARY"'
echo "Subject: Test Message"
echo ""
echo "This is a MIME-encapsulated message"
echo "--BOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo ""
echo "This is what someone would see without an HTML capable mail client."
echo ""
echo "--BOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>
<body bgcolor='black'>
<blockquote><font color='green'>GREEN</font> <font color='white'>WHITE</font> <font color='red'>RED</font></blockquote>
</body>
</html>"
echo "--BOUNDARY--"
) | sendmail -t
```

#### References

- [How do I send mail from linux command line so it appears as HTML to recipient?](https://serverfault.com/questions/103097/how-do-i-send-mail-from-linux-command-line-so-it-appears-as-html-to-recipient)

Comment: Same problem: `Error in command line: content_type: unknown variable` - Also, I'm not sure if that would give me utf-8-encoded attachments.

Comment: Both give the same error.  
Which mutt version do you have? I didn't find out how to get the version number, but my docs (`/usr/share/doc`) have version `mutt-1.4.2.2`.

Comment: `mutt -v`.  I have this: Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15)

Comment: Then it's probably a version problem. I'll try to update mutt (problematic, because it's not my own system...).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9225/discussion-between-martin-and-slm)

Comment: A nit regarding the `sendmail` solution: the last '--BOUNDARY' must be '--BOUNDARY--' instead

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt - no by all means we want this to be correct. Thanks I didn't even notice! I've updated it in the answer.

Comment: @slm I managed to make perl output my xml file as utf-8 (at least it says so now in the source code of the received email). But I had to include non-iso-characters (`<?comment <!-- ł € --> ?>`) in my xml to trigger this. A simple `ä` was not enough...